# Create Matrix where its entries come from functions

Tags: functions, matrix

I want to create matrix `A` of `N x N` where its entries, `aij`, come from two different functions. For example, as follows:

The first column comes from for `i=1,...N`:

```
ai1[i_] := i^2;
```

Other elements come from for `i=1,...,N` and `j=2,..,N`:

```
aij[i_, j_] := 2 i j;
```

How can I create this `A` matrix in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `Array` or `Table`.

```
n = 5;
(amat = Array[If[#2 == 1, #1^2, 2 #1 #2] &, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm

(bmat = Table[If[j == 1, i^2, 2 i j], {i, n}, {j, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

Or using `SparseArray`:

```
(cmat = Normal@SparseArray[
     {{i_, 1} -> i^2, {i_, j_} -> 2 i j}, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

---

Result:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\
 9 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 30 \\
 16 & 16 & 24 & 32 & 40 \\
 25 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Really helpful all your suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, another possibility is the following (8 more left to get to 10 :)

```
N0 = 5;
ai1[i_] := i^2;
ai1[i_, j_] := 2*i*j;
first = Table[ai1[i], {i, N0}];
rest = Table[ai1[i, j], {i, N0}, {j, 2, N0}];
Transpose@Insert[Transpose@rest, first, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it too cheap to sub `Transpose` by `Thread` and count it as the third option? :D (just joking)

Comment: Thanks for this alternative approach too!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility

```
n = 5;
first = Table[i^2, {i, n}];
rest = Table[2 i j, {i, n}, {j, 2, n}];
MatrixForm@ArrayReshape[Thread@{first, rest}, {n, n}]
```

> [image: mat]

Comment: Very helpful this approach as well!